# Use a cancellation Token to cancel multiple Tasks

Tags: c#, winforms, task, cancellation-token

I want to know how to cancel Tasks. already read some articles like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads?redirectedfrom=MSDN

But i have already done Tasks and want to know how can i make them cancelable.

Either all at once and if that is not possible then one task should be canceled and then he should cancel the next one until all are gone.

****EDIT* Is that the correct using of CancellationToken?
Tasks continue to run as I wanted, but when I press the cancel button I get an error. If I start my published version, the application just closes:****
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQTyg.jpg)

```
 void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            cts.Cancel();

        }
   

       async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = cts.Token;
            var t1 = Task.Run(() => START(token));
            await Task.WhenAny(new[] { t1 });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Handle canceled
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Handle other exceptions
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    async void START(CancellationToken token)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(100, token);
             try { 
              
                    if()
                    {
                        
                    }

            }catch { }  
        }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        var t2 = Task.Run(() => START2(token));
        await Task.WhenAny(new[] { t2});
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
   async void START2(CancellationToken token)
    {
       
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(100, token);
             try { 
              
                    if()
                    {
                        
                    }

            }catch { }  
        }
        Thread.Sleep(7000);


        var t3 = Task.Run(() => MOVE(token));
        await Task.WhenAny(new[] {t3});
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////
   async void MOVE(CancellationToken token)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(100, token);
            try { 
              
                    if()
                    {

                    }

            }catch { }

        }
        var t4 = Task.Run(() => MOVE2(token));
        await Task.WhenAny(new[] {t4 });

    }
```

Comment: The article you linked goes into a lot of detail. Which bit of it don't you understand? There's no point in us saying the same thing as the article...

Comment: I was hoping for a construct that I could use in my tasks. In the article I don't understand how to end all tasks with one button, because I use await tasks. And in the article it feels like everything is in one main and one then goes out on a "DoSomeWork" task.. But I need it on several tasks at the same time and I can't find what I'm looking for or I'm just blind and overlook it constant. :/? I tried it and i cannot use the cancel token   cts.Cancel(); on my Stop Button because there is not global i think?

Comment: You create a single `CancellationTokenSource`, and pass the value of its `.Token` parameter (which is a `CancellationToken`) to all of your tasks, where you check whether it's been cancelled by calling `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` regularly, and catch the resulting `OperationCanceledException` where appropriate. When your button is clicked, you call `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CancellationTokenSource, in a somewhat simplified example:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
async void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cts.Cancel();
}
async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try{
       cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
       var token = cts.Token;
       var t1 = Task.Run(() => Start(token));
       var t2 = Task.Run(() => Start(token));
       await Task.WhenAny(new []{t1, t2});
    }
    catch(OperationCancelledException){
        // Handle canceled
    }
    catch(Exception){
        // Handle other exceptions
    }
}

void Start(CancellationToken token)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
         token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
         // Do work 
         Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked it will first create a new cancellationTokenSource, then start two tasks on background threads, both using the token from the newly created token source. When the cancelButton is pressed the token will be set into canceled-state, and the next time each background thread calls ThrowIfCancellationRequested they will throw an exception. This will put the task into a canceled-state, and awaiting this will throw an operationCancelledException that need to be caught. Note that when awaiting multiple tasks you might get an [aggregateException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-6.0) that wraps multiple exceptions and need to be unpacked.

Comment: It would be better practice, if possible, to use `await Task.Delay(100, token)` rather than `Thread.Sleep`, so that the sleep is cancelled as soon as the token is cancelled. Then you don't need the `Task.Run` either.

Comment: `Task.WhenAny`? Did you intended to write `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: thanks for your work. really good and easy to understand :) One question i have. my tasks are all started with await because there are async... how can i start this task with await ? var t1 = await Task.Run(() => RESTART(token)); is not correct... and my tasks starts after there are done the next task.. how can i solve this with your code? i dont want to start all tasks in once or did i have something understand wrong?

Comment: i edited my post and convert my tasks to this. is this correct? 
Tasks continue to run as I wanted, but when I press the cancel button I get an error. If I start my published version, the application just closes. if i edit my code like yours: var t1 = Task.Run(() => Start(token));
       var t2 = Task.Run(() => Start(token)); then it starts two task in one time

Comment: @steven you likely have an exception closing your application, see my note about aggregateException, and check the windows event viewer why your application was closed. Also, I would really not recommend using async functions that way. Keep it simple, run some compute-bound work on a background thread and handle the result on the UI thread.

Comment: Big Thanks, It took me a long time to understand it, but I got it now. It's exactly how I imagined it :)